# Values are not getting inserted into Hashmap

Tags: java

```
public class FileReaderServer implements Runnable
{
    private Map<String, String> mapp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void searchWords()
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null )
            {
                boolean success = tree.search(line);
                if ( success )
                    mapp.put(line, "TRUE");
                else
                    mapp.put(line, "FALSE");
            }
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            System.out.println( ex );
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        searchWords();
    }

    public void printMap()
    {
        Iterator it = mapp.entrySet().iterator();
        while ( it.hasNext() ) 
        {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try
        {
            FileReaderServer server = new FileReaderServer("keywords.txt");
            server.createTree();

            Thread t1 = new Thread(new FileReaderServer());
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new FileReaderServer());
            Thread t3 = new Thread(new FileReaderServer());             

            t1.start();
            t2.start();
            t3.start();

            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();

            server.printMap();
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

This is cut-down version of my original class enough to figure out issue I believe. ( if not please let me know to paste some more code.)

Issue is that in "printMap" nothing is getting printed. However, code has reached

```
boolean success = tree.search(line);
if ( success )
{
    System.out.println(line + "TRUE");   // This is getting printed.
    mapp.put(line, "TRUE");
}
else
    mapp.put(line, "FALSE");
```

EDIT :- One more question here. I'm trying to make `searchWords` `synchronized`. However, I am passing different instances to each of the created thread.So, is synchronization a property of object OR a class. i.e whether any of these threads could be executing that function concurrently.

Comment: Please, if you post code, make sure it compiles when one copy pastes it.

Comment: .... you have several **compile** errors in the code, never mind what the rest of your code "isn't" doing: `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));` - where is `input` coming from?  If you're trying to multi-thread this, don't directly use `Thread`, use the pool.  You'll also need to synchronize use of IO, or things will end poorly.  And just use the Boolean true/false values, not strings...

Comment: @ravi I've updated my answer (below UPD1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass another instance of FileReaderServer to each thread:

```
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new FileReaderServer());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new FileReaderServer());
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new FileReaderServer());
```

But you try to get values from:

```
        FileReaderServer server = new FileReaderServer("keywords.txt");

...

        server.printMap();
```

If you will pass **server** instance to each of these three threads - you will get unexpected behaviour due unsynchronized nature of **java.util.HashMap**. Replace it with **java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap**.

**UPD1** If you will mark *searchWords()* as **synchronized** - you will loose all benefits of concurrency, because all your 3 threads will execute *searchWords()* sequentially.

So I'm still insist on using **ConcurrentHashMap**:

```
private Map<String, String> mapp = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
```

Or you may simply wrap **HashMap** instance with **Collections.synchronizedMap(...)** like this:

```
private Map<String, String> mapp = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, String>())
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, that you try to get your lines from `server`. But the server object will not get started. You have to start your threads like so:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(server);
Thread t2 = new Thread(server);
Thread t3 = new Thread(server);
```

In this case you have to think about good synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the `HashMap` member of the `FileReaderServer` instance referred by the `server` variable, but that's not the `HashMap` you are adding entries to.

You are adding the entries to the `HashMap`s of the `FileReaderServer` instances passed to the `Thread`s you are creating.

You may want to make `mapp` static if you want it to be shared by all instances of `FileReaderServer`. However, if you do that, you may encounter synchronization issues, so perhaps you should use a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: Thanks got my mistake...I would rather use "static" map and then make the method synchronized. What abt that?

Comment: @ravi using static HashMap instance is not enough. You should think about concurrent access. I propose to use ConcurrentHashMap.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the Constructor that takes a String File-name. Create a constructor that takes a String file-name as parameter.

```
FileReaderServer server = new FileReaderServer("keywords.txt");
```

Where are you initializing the variable input in:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
```

When it creates a thread FileReaderServer does not know which file to read.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new FileReaderServer());
```